# Windows 10 hosted network = "no", how to force yes

Tags: cmd

I've been trying to create a hosted network with my laptop.
Programms like "Connectify" work, but the built-in function does not.
Command NETSH WLAN show drivers gives me the following information.
Hosted network supported  : No

Now to my question: How do programs like connectify circumvent this limitation and how can I do this manually?

Answer (score 2):

I would look into whether the built-in Mobile hotspot settings in Windows 10 would work for you.

Run `ms-settings:network-mobilehotspot` to go there directly.
This is what I found and used recently to solve the same issue you were having.

Additional note: You can also access it within the notification panel as well:

[image]